# Get data using twig - (list all objects)

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig

I need you litle help!

I have this widget template from a webstore. But this widget list online reviews from one product only. And I need get listing all rating and reviews.

```
    {% if testimonials|count > 0 %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getScript('{{ global_js('jquery.raty.js') }}', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {

        $('.rating-stars-view').each(function(){
          var name = $(this).data('name');
          $(this).raty({
            path: '{{ global_asset('img/') }}', 
            score: function() {
              return $(this).attr('data-score');
            },
            readOnly: true
          });
        });

      });
    });
   </script>
   <div class="testimonials">
    <h2>Notas totais</h2>
    <ul class="testimonials-rating-totals" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <li style="display:none">
        <span itemprop="reviewCount">{{ testimonials|count }}</span>
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">{{ testimonial_totals.total }}</span>
      </li>
      <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial_totals.total }}"></div>Média geral </li>
      <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial_totals.rating_look }}"></div>Beleza do produto </li>
      <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial_totals.rating_usability }}"></div>Usabilidade do produto </li>
      <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial_totals.rating_support }}"></div>Atendimento e segurança </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <h2>O que clientes dizem</h2>
    <div class="testimonials-listing">
      {% for testimonial in testimonials %}
        <div class="testimonial row" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <strong class="testimonial-author" itemprop="author">{{ testimonial.firstname }}</strong> escreveu na data  
            <strong class="testimonial-date" itemprop="datePublished">{{ testimonial.created_at|to_formated_date }}</strong>:
            <div class="testimonial-message" itemprop="description">{{ testimonial.message }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="testimonials-ratings" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
              <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial.total }}" itemprop="ratingValue" content="{{ testimonial.total }}"></div>Média geral</li>
              <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial.rating_look}}"></div>Beleza do produto</li>
              <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial.rating_usability }}"></div>Usabilidade do produto</li>
              <li><div class="rating-stars-view pull-left" data-score="{{ testimonial.rating_support }}"></div>Atendimento e segurança</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
           <hr>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>

    {% endif %}
```

How to? I don't have php access. I have access to html and twig structure only.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do without access to the PHP.  Whatever defines `testimonials` would need to be updated.

Comment: tks for your reply. but 'testimonials' in this widget list from one product, because the product page gets using product Id. I think there's if i send multiples id's, using an loop or each function is the solution, but i don't know how to send multiples id's using an loop.